# remove "" from output

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Im trying to write to a CSV-File, the output should look like this:

```
 meist,L, ,meist (30), meisten (95)
```

**But It looks like this, the joined strings get `"`:**

```
 meist,L, ,"meist (30), meisten (95)"
```

My code is the following one:

```
      with open(dest_csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['wortstamm', 'words'])
        writer.writeheader()
        for wortstamm in self.ausgabe:

            words = []
            for word in self.ausgabe[wortstamm]["w"]:
                words.append('' + word + ' (' + str(self.ausgabe[wortstamm]["w"][word]) + ')')

            words_string = ', '.join(words)

            writer.writerow({'wortstamm': wortstamm, 'words': words_string})
```

**How do I get my code to write the desired output?** What do I have to change? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please provide a sample snippet of the input?

Comment: In `words.append(` the `word` variable is a normal string. `self.ausgabe[wortstamm]["w"][word]` is an integer. @albert does this help you? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that includes the input data that produces the output line `meist,L, ,"meist (30), meisten (95)"`? I'm having difficulty seeing how this program would produce that ouput when you've defined a csv.DictWriter with just two fields.

Comment: The csv writer object writes the commas for you, you aren't supposed to add them yourself.

Comment: @interjay Could you please write your comment as answer. My programm added the `"` because of `', '.join( ` Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the fields you give to the csv writer contains a `,`, it will be wrapped by quotes so that it will not be considered as multiple fields. If you have multiple fields, you should pass them in separately instead of joining them with a comma as in your code.

Since it seems that your fields come from a list, it may be easier to use `csv.writer` (which is given a list of fields for each row) instead of `csv.DictWriter` (which is given a dictionary where each field is specified by name).

Example:

```
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
for wortstamm in self.ausgabe:
     words = ....
     writer.writerow([wortstamm] + words)
```